# How long should I wait before creating an undo command when I'm typing text?

Tags: text, text-editor, undo

I'm working on an undo chain in my project. I want to avoid undoing individual letters, but instead undo chunks of text. Therefore, I'm working with a debounce.

Is there a standard waiting time or a best practice to follow? I see that browsers and Word all work approximately the same, so I thought there might be a standard way of doing this.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'm not sure of any standards for this, but I'd start with creating undo "frames" **after a .4 or .5 second pause**, see how it feels and what your users think of it, then tweak from there.

Additionally, I might **cap it at a certain number of words** (perhaps 6 or 8). If a user is a very fast typist, and is consistently outpacing *whatever debounce you pick*, they should still be able to benefit from your undo feature—it just might not be as finely-tuned to match their behavior.

Obviously this needs to be accompanied by a "redo" ability.

Comment: Hmm, capping the number of words is definitely a good idea! Thanks